# What is Precedence/order of resolution of an instance's runmode coming from different configurations

Tags: aem

FOR AEM 6.0

I can see in the documentation that following is the correct order, but, when i am trying practically, this is not working, can someone help me understand it?-

> 1. sling.properties file
> 2. -r option
> 3. system properties (-D)
> 4. Filename detection

**ONE**- I am not able to find the sling.properties file when i unpack( `-unpack`) the jar file for the first time, so unable to edit this.

**TWO**- i ran a command on command line,

```
java -Dsling.run.modes=author,dev,qa -jar cq-author-4502.jar
```

but, when i am seeing this-

```
localhost:4502/system/console/status-slingsettings
```

it is showing that the run mode is `author` only, while it should have been `author,dev,qa`

Comment: You provided not enough information to help you. Provide info what you've tried and what result is.

Comment: @Alex i have provided more details, can you plase help me understand this query?

Comment: Also, can you please specify CQ/AEM version you use?

Comment: Also what do you mean by words 'when i unpack the jar file for the first time'? Is it starting jar file with '-unpack' option?

Comment: Yes. I meant -unpack option!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've specified author in the naming of the jar file (i.e.cq-author-4502.jar), hence it takes precedence.

The order is:

1. jar file name contains run mode
2. then values specified in sling.properties file if run mode is not specified in jar name
3. then system property or what you specify on the command line if 1 and 2 are not specified

See [Adobe run modes](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/RunModeSetUp.html) for more details.

Comment: but something else is written in the Adobe Docs! i mentioned the order of resolution in my question itself.

Comment: The order you mention in your question is not what the link I sent says.  The Adobe link states as per my summary. Check out the Adobe link I sent.

Comment: Okay, So adobe itself is giving different order at different places. I am referring this one- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/configuring/configure-runmodes.html#Starting%20CQ%20with%20a%20specific%20run%20mode . Which one to consider?

Comment: I just tested this, the precedence/order is as per my original post and the link I sent. Note that I tested using version 6.1 of AEM  but this also applies to your version 6.0 too.